How can I find the median of two sorted arrays in O(log(m+n)) complexity
I copy the length of two initial arrays and then merge them into a third array and the length of the third array is equal to the length of initial two arrays added together. Then I try to find the median of the merged array.
class Solution {
    public double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {
      
        int[] a = nums1;
        int[] b = nums2;

        int c = a.length + b.length;

        int[] myArr = new int[c];

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            myArr[i] = a[i]; 
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            myArr[a.length + i] = b[i]; 
        }

        Arrays.sort(myArr);

        double median;
        int lastIndex = myArr.length - 1;

        int middle = lastIndex / 2;

        if (myArr.length % 2 != 0) {
            median = myArr[middle];
        } else {
            median = (myArr[middle] + myArr[middle + 1]) / 2.0;
        }

        return median;

    }
}


Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is mostly for questions where you need the help of another developer. Please do some cursory research before posting a question; it will be much better-received by the community to do so. (In your case, a Google search for your question title was enough for me to get some answers.) Read how to ask for more information.

In general, if the question is about improving code that works, asking at Code Review is better. However, in either case, and as suggested in the first comment, you are expected to do some research before asking.

I think this question should be deleted, there are enough of them..
Also, there is an exhaustive explanation on leetcode:
https://leetcode.com/problems/median-of-two-sorted-arrays/editorial/

@AlexPakka Or at least closed for being a duplicate. I noticed the answer hasn't met the  O(log(m+n)) requirement.

This question is similar to: Understanding the algorithm of "Median of Two Sorted Arrays". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Using two pointer (here):
public double findMedianSortedArrays(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int size1 = arr1.length;
    int size2 = arr2.length;
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    while (i < size1 && j < size2) {
        if (arr1[i] < arr2[j]) {
            result.add(arr1[i++]);
        } else {
            result.add(arr2[j++]);
        }
    }

    while (i < size1) {
        result.add(arr1[i++]);
    }
    while (j < size2) {
        result.add(arr2[j++]);
    }

    int mid = result.size() / 2;
    if (result.size() % 2 == 0) {
        return (result.get(mid - 1) + result.get(mid)) / 2.0;
    }
    return result.get(mid);
}


This would be O(m+n), not O(log(m+n))...but you could probably modify this answer with binary search to get the log complexity, perhaps even without using a second array to copy into.

@JeffBowman Oh, thank you sir! I'll update my post.
